# How to change size of JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to set the size for frame that contains MVC:

```
chartModel = new ChartModel();
chartModel.setChartData(dataName, data);

pieChart = new PieChart();
barChart = new BarChart();

setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 2));

pieChart.setModel(chartModel);
add(pieChart);

barChart.setModel(chartModel);
add(barChart); 

public static void main(String[] args) {
Chart chart = new Chart();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

frame.setTitle("Chart");

frame.setSize(600,420);
//frame.setSize(400,320);

frame.add(chart, BorderLayout.CENTER);

chart.init();
chart.start();

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This however does not make any effect no matter how I change parameters for setSize.

Am I missing something? Please help!

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with MVC .. unless you understand it as "My Very Code".

Comment: where the heck does the code above your main sit? Can you put the code the way you have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmm I recommend use a different way to program swing... is more easy
you use another class for declare a windows motor, for example :

```
public class Console {

public static void run (final JFrame f, final int width, final int height) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            f.setTitle(f.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setSize(width, height);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
    });

}
```

now, you have a class console and when you create this object, you should pass a Jframe and de windows dimension

for create a Jframe, you should create in another class, for exemple:

```
    public class nameClass extends JFrame{

    //code

    public nameClass(){ // constructor
       Chart chart = new Chart();
       setTitle("Chart");
       add(chart, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       chart.init();
       chart.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          Console.run(new nameClass(),300,400);
    }
```

This form for create a Window is the best because using a another execution thread and no overload...

I hope you help serve
good lucky